# Multicast message on same host using boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost, ip, boost-asio, multicast

I'm implementing sender/receiver applications to talk multicast on the same host.

In my constructor, I have the following code to setup the socket.

```
boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listenEndpoint(listenAddr, mcastPort);
m_socket.open(listenEndpoint.protocol());
m_socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
m_socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::enable_loopback(true));
m_socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::hops(1));
m_socket.bind(listenEndpoint);

// Join the multicast group
m_socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(mcastAddr));

m_socket.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(m_data, MAX_PTP_MSG_LENGTH),
        m_senderEndpoint, boost::bind(&PtpIpc::HandleReceiveFrom, this, 
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

Where listenAddr is 0.0.0.0.

My sending method code is as follows:

```
m_socket.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(data, size), m_remoteEndpoint,
    boost::bind(&PtpIpc::HandleSendTo, this,
    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

Where m_remoteEndpoint is multicast address 224.0.1.129 and muticast port 320.

Application A doesn't seem to receive multicast messages from Application B and vice versa when both are on the same host.  But if I move Application B to another machine on the same subnet... then Application A hears multicast message and reply back to Application B, which can also receive the reply message from Application A.  I've enabled loopback and also set the socket reuse_address option.  What am I missing?

Comment: This behavior is pretty common; I've also seen it on completely different OSes such as Tru64 Unix.  What OS are you using?

Comment: @Ben I'm developing under Timesys with Linux kernel 2.6.29.  Thanks!

Comment: Are both application A and B joining the multicast group, and both sending and receiving to/from the group?  Also, do you have separate sockets for receiving from the multicast group vs. sending to the group?

Comment: @Dave: Yes, both application A and B joined the multicast group and sending/receiving to/from the same group. As I mentioned initially, they both talk fine when on separate machines, just doesn't work when on the same host. I use the same socket to send and receive to the group and also tried using separate sockets...but neither way works when on the same machine.

Comment: Well, I would recommend trying having separate send/receive sockets, and binding your receive sockets to the multicast address.  It's how I usually do it, and I haven't had the problem you describe.

Comment: @OP: Did you find a solution? I do have the exactly same problem. I am binding the receive socket to the multicast address.

Comment: If you have to use `boost::asio::ip::multicast::enable_loopback(true)` for sender socket as well, no?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you remove the loopback option. I've had a similar issue and removing that fixed it.